# How to create a Search bar with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

search : ____________

I want to create a search bar and when user tries to enter the input text which is equal 8word or more then its should trigger and store the variable and reset the search bar and check with backend API and one's found in backend then its should show the count increment or ELSE if not found then should show in table.

Note : I want to trigger this without search button and space should not be count.

for example:

search : qwerr121

Found:
count : 1

Not found table:
qwerr121

if text == 16:
check with backend
found = found + 1
else:
array = [qwerr121]

Thank you

Here is my js code but how can i do with angular

```js
   JS code: 
const input = document.getElementById('input');
let data;
 
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const inputValue = e.target.value;
 
  if (inputValue.length === 11) {
    data = inputValue;
 
    e.target.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
Html: 
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: this seems more like an assignment for us. :)

Comment: Use `(change)` event on your input. `<input (change)="yourFunction(abc)"  [(ngModel)]="abc"/>`

Comment: i have try some method but its not working so i thought to share my problem with everyone to get help or at least some idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for but i made this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zbuypx?file=src/app/app.component.html